# How to write custom accessors for an NSManagedObject subclass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a view called `Cart`. It displays a table of `Item`s. These `Item`s need to persist, so `Item` subclasses NSManagedObject; values like `id`, `price`, etc. are properties whose accessors are `@dynamic` so that they are automagically generated.

I have another view called `Favorites`. It displays a table of `Item`s, but they don't need to persist. In fact, this view changes whenever the user logs in with different credentials.

The connection between the two views is that the user can add items to his cart from his favorites. A cart can store `Item`s from different `Favorites` lists. `Favorites` lists don't change when the item is added to the cart.

Initially, I made the model for the `Favorites` view be an NSArray of NSDictionary objects. When the user adds the item to his cart, I create and save the item in Core Data from the NSDictionary key-value pairs. This approach doesn't look very clean or very DRY. Wouldn't it make more sense to make the `Favorites` view's model be an NSArray of `Item`s?

So now my intent is to implement the `Item` class so that it will represent the Core Data model (NSManagedObject), but also work with the `Favorites` view. Being new to Objective-C and iOS development, I really don't know how this would work or look like. It seems that I would need to override the accessors that are magically created for me, but I can't call them at compile time using a `super` call... Can anyone give me a rough outline of when it would know to return the NSDictionary data or the Core Data data? In the case that it's Core Data data, how do I maintain the same level of efficiency that the magically-generated accessors would have?

Even better, is there a better implementation that is just as DRY or makes more sense? Or am I trying to combine too much functionality into one class? Is the NSArray of NSDictionary objects the best way to go in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a result type on your fetch request (object, objectID, count, dictionary).

Also, I would not use NSManagedObjects outside of a MOC.  You should either have a separate object that you use for memory stuff, or you can use an in-memory persistent store for those objects...  or, you can just create a separate MOC as a child to your main database MOC that you use for your in-memory objects.

The advantage of these approaches is that your code does not have to know whether they are backed to the disk or not.

As long as you do not save the MOC, the changes to those objects will never go to disk.

**EDIT**

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = // create the fetch request...
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
```

Now, when you make the fetch, instead of getting back an array of NSManagedObject you will get back an array of NSDictionary.

Comment: Would you mind being a little more specific by what you mean by your first sentence? I'm still getting used to Objective-C and iOS, so what would those various function prototypes look like? Thanks!

Comment: @JodyHagins +1 for your answer